# How to run openwrt image as a docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openwrt

I'm new to docker. What I want to do is run an openwrt bin file inside a docker container and compile socketman source inside that docker image. 
this is the image file
http://download.gl-inet.com.s3.amazonaws.com/firmware/b1300/v1/qsdk-b1300-2.272.bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to compile some source(socketman) to openwrt. Here is my work around.

I downloaded the sdk for appropriate firmware. (There is the bin file and also the SDK.)

If you have sdk then you dont have to build the toolchain. tools are already there. (If you get SDK then the build process faster other than compiling whole firmware)

Then cd into the sdk directory. place your source code inside the `package` directory.

then in the terminal (inside the appropriate SDK folder) type `make menuconfig`

[image]

Then `star` the package you want to build
save and exit

then type `make` if you want to log out the debug info type `make -j4 V=s`
-j4 means the available # of cors, you can put the # of cores that you have on your computer.`nproc`

**If you want to build inside a docker container.**

install docker

then clone ubuntu docker image

run the docker image with interactive shell

git clone or wget SDK folder into the docker container

then proceed all the above steps.